# Is it possible to host multiple domain TLS in golang with net/http?

Tags: go, https, http2

I have multiple domain (let's say abc.com and xyz.org) with diffrent certificate. Is it possible to use key and certificate based on hostname without going deep low level and net.Listen, etc. Just using simple http.ListenAndServeTLS(...) or similar ?
Basically like what nginx does.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

BuildNameToCertificate() will sniff the hostname from the cert.  If none match the SNI info it serves the [0].
https://golang.org/src/crypto/tls/common.go?s=18204:18245#L947

Update for Go 1.14 - see https://github.com/golang/go/commit/eb93c684d40de4924fc0664d7d9e98a84d5a100b

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "log"
)

func myHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("tls"))
}

func main() {
    t := log.Logger{}
    var err error
    tlsConfig := &tls.Config{}
    tlsConfig.Certificates = make([]tls.Certificate, 3)
    // go http server treats the 0'th key as a default fallback key
    tlsConfig.Certificates[0], err = tls.LoadX509KeyPair("test0.pem", "key.pem")
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    tlsConfig.Certificates[1], err = tls.LoadX509KeyPair("test1.pem", "key.pem")
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    tlsConfig.Certificates[2], err = tls.LoadX509KeyPair("test2.pem", "key.pem")
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }

    // as of go 1.14 this line is no longer needed
    // load the certs as above and skip BuildNameToCertificate()
    tlsConfig.BuildNameToCertificate()

    http.HandleFunc("/", myHandler)
    server := &http.Server{
        ReadTimeout:    10 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
        MaxHeaderBytes: 1 << 20,
        TLSConfig:      tlsConfig,
    }

    listener, err := tls.Listen("tcp", ":8443", tlsConfig)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Fatal(server.Serve(listener))
}
```

Comment: server doesn't have any StartTLS method!

Comment: Corrected with a working example.  This more complete example properly creates the listener and starts the server.

Comment: How should I add my router here?

Comment: @foo I am using gorilla mux for routing. I was using only one certificate earlier. So, I used http.ListenAndServe(port,cert,key,router). How can I use same router here?

Comment: @Saransh this technique supersedes ListenAndServer().
For gorilla, just replace myHandler with your mux.Router reference

Comment: Heads up tls.NameToCertificate is deprecated. 

NameToCertificate only allows associating a single certificate with a given name. Leave that field nil to let the library select the first compatible chain from Certificates.